# Kill processes automatically that get over x % CPU

Tags: terminal, activity-monitor, macos, processor

I have a (rather annoying) process on my iMac that tends to get out of control.

<sub>Unfortunately, it's not possible to get rid of it. Much as I want to.</sub>

This process is *fine* at first - using 1-2 % of my dual-core CPU.

Then it happens. The entire machine slows down. If I can manage to get Activity Monitor open, I can see that the offending process is using 200%, even *300%* of my CPU.

Not fun.

If I can get Activity Monitor or Terminal open, and kill the process, it will restart itself and behave like a good little process. For a while. The it goes crazy again.

Being an iOS developer, I'm thinking that the best way to combat this process is an automated assistant.

What I have in mind is a background process that would kill the offending process as soon as its CPU usage hits X%, say 50 or 75%. The the process will restart and become sane without my intervention.

Is it possible? I can write code, AppleScript, *anything* to make the machine usable again.

Comment: Is this a user process, or a system process? Have you tried `nice` on the process?

Comment: @demure Nope. What's the usage, and what does it do?

Comment: `nice` can change the scheduling priority of a process. see `man nice`[*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nice). Example: `nice -n 19 process_name`

Comment: @Undo what is the process that misbehaves?

Comment: @Undo Under OSX anti vurus programs call more issues than they solve :) One of he reasons many prople recommend not using them

Comment: @Mark We don't use the AV part. I'm an iOS Dev :)

Comment: @Undo uninstall Intego antivirus, you don't need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/97541/kill-process-with-high-cpu-usage-after-x-time) suggest using [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/).
As you have given no details as to the nature of the process, I can't advise whether their suggested config would be of any use for you.

Comment: Does that run on OSX? the blog is for Linux and the download page ncludes several Unicies nut not OSX. I ask as i is likelyto deal with system level APIs which differ in OSX.

Comment: As you can see from the [download page](http://mmonit.com/monit/download/), there is a 
macosx-universal binary.

Comment: SOrry I missed that the first time I read it